# Could not autowire field SessionFactory when I load context manually

Tags: java, spring, autowired, xml-configuration

I have the following `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        ">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/dataContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/restTemplateContext.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/securityContext.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.terminal" >
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

`dataContext.xml`:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.terminal.domain, com.terminal.dao, com.terminal.utils"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <task:scheduler id="jobScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

    <beans profile="test">

        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    </beans>
    <beans profile="dev">

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc-local.properties"/>
        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
              p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="prod">

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
              p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </beans>
```

I load context like this:

```
ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

But I see the following error:

```
Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.terminal.dao.admin.impl.AdminRoleDaoImpl.sessionFactory
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

In diiferent with this situation when I load context from web.xml it works fine.

`web.xml` content:

```
<web-app
     ...

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>test</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/webContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

How to avoid exception when I load context manually ?

Comment: why are you even loading it manually? generally loading it manually means you are doing something wrong...

Comment: @M. Deinum I use hibernate validator to validate fields. But I should read annotation arguments from database. In database resides argument for **@Min** annotation for example thus I should go to database to validate field. As I understand spring knows about hibernate but hibernate doesn't know anything about spring.

Comment: Still you shouldn't be loading it because you need it, you are effectively loading your whole application again. Eventually this will lead to strange performance issues, database issues (locks for instance). Also the `@Min` annotations  are quite static so not sure what you need to load from the database.

Comment: But I have the following task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set profile for spring. Your code should look like this:

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: It is near to right answer I think but I have the problem that spring loads context simultaneously and I set hbm2ddl to create and I see exceptions